# Can't have control with id="Title"

Tags: asp.net, webforms

In a webform, I have a textbox (using `<asp:TextBox`) using "Title" as its ID. No error at compile, but browser then returns error saying:

```
BC30311: Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'
```

Then I found out that `Page` object also has `Title` property. Error disappeared after changing the textbox's ID with another name. Using HTML's `<input type="textbox" id="Title" runat="server"` also causes error.

Is this normal, that "Title" can't be used as control's ID?

Comment: Are you using `Title` at code behind for anything?

Comment: @Andrei: Yes, for some database process.

Answer (score 3):

A serverside control with an `ID` causes a member with that name to be generated in the partial designer class. This will hide the existing member named `Title`.

It works perfectly fine if you do, but then in code behind `this.Title` will refer to the *control*, but not the *member*.

So the code that shows the error in your question must be something like `this.Title = "Hello, World!"`, trying to assign a string to a TextBox.

Comment: So in other word, a webform can't have any control with `Title` as ID. Is it right?

Comment: @Rahul thanks you're right, I've got my member hiding mixed up. Latest edit should fix the confusion. Removing my comments.

Comment: @CodeCaster - Yup agree, OP must be doing this :) +1

Comment: Looks like I did :-). I'm using like (VB) `Me.Title.Text = xx` or `Dim xx = Me.Title.Text`. I'm sure `Title.Text` is fine. I'll do a check.

Comment: @CodeCaster: I'm sorry I undo this as accepted answer. I name a textbox as `Title` and in code behind I do like `Title.Text = xx` for same error. I try using a `<div id="Title" runat="server"` and doesn't touch it at all in code behind, for `BC30311: Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl` error.

Comment: Show all relevant code and the entire error in your question, then. That error still looks like _somewhere_ in your code (master page, perhaps?) you still have something like `this.Title = "Foo"`.